# GPPSignIn crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I tried to set up Google+ Sign in for iOS using [Google+ Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in) guide. Previously I have also followed [Google Platform Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) guide.

My code is as following:

```
- (void)didTapSignIn {
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.clientID = PTCGoogleClientID;
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    signIn.attemptSSO = YES;
    signIn.delegate = self;
    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

But instead of having Google sign in dialog, I got this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: state)'
```

More detail on the crash log:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x03654916 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032f28d9 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x035450bc -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 940
3   MyApp                               0x0015172c -[GPPSignIn oauth2URLWithParams:] + 450
4   MyApp                               0x001518f4 -[GPPSignIn doOAuthLoginWithParams:] + 107
5   MyApp                               0x00151d24 -[GPPSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithParams:] + 91
6   MyApp                               0x00151f96 -[GPPSignIn authenticateMaybeInteractively:withParams:] + 610
7   MyApp                               0x0014ecb1 -[GPPSignIn authenticate] + 49
8   MyApp                               0x0001c8e4 -[MyAppController tapGoogleLogin:] + 132
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x033057bf -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
10  UIKit                               0x016dc1fe -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
11  UIKit                               0x016dc190 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
12  UIKit                               0x01804786 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
13  UIKit                               0x01804ba3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
14  UIKit                               0x01803e0d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
15  UIKit                               0x0172814a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
16  UIKit                               0x01728c25 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
17  UIKit                               0x016f30a5 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
18  UIKit                               0x0170075e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13892
19  UIKit                               0x016d6b64 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1561
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0357930f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0356dc99 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 249
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0356d1f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0356cb7b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0356c9ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
25  GraphicsServices                    0x04ded500 GSEventRunModal + 192
26  GraphicsServices                    0x04ded33d GSEventRun + 104
27  UIKit                               0x016dadee UIApplicationMain + 3727
28  MyApp                               0x00026cad main + 141
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x03aeeac5 start + 1
30  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Could somebody point me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: This problem happened when I tried to compile the code on XCode 6. It runs normal in XCode 5.1.1.

Comment: do have have any idea why this code crashes the app in Xcode 6.x? I am facing the same problem. My Xcode version is 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downloaded XCode 6 Beta 2, released by Apple on June 17th. Then, I retried the code and it runs fine.

Comment: I am facing same problem even on Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a). Will you please check it whether your project is running perfectly or not? If yes please send me the sample project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time.
But if some one still get this crash you need to add `-Objc` in **Other Linker Flags**.

[Full Description here - Common Issues With Google+ Sign-In On iOS](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/06/common-issues-with-google-sign-in-on-ios.html)

Also, you will need to add frameworks mentioned in **Step 2** here -

[Start integrating Google+ into your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)